# How to install AWS eksctl on Windows without using Chocolatey

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, chocolatey, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am working on a strictly configured windows pc which has some very restricted ExecutionPolicy set which doesn't let me install Chocolatey even with non-admin installation version of Chocolatey. Is there a way to install AWS eksctl as described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-eksctl.html without using Chocolatey?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [snoop](https://scoop.sh/), [gofish](https://gofi.sh/#intro) or just download [binary](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/releases/download/0.19.0/eksctl_Windows_amd64.zip) directly from release [pages](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/releases) :)